# org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/1.1.1 can't get javax.transaction.TransactionManager

Tags: maven, karaf, aries

I've created maven distribution using karaf-maven-plugin.

I've created maven project using

> mvn archetype:generate -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.karaf.archetypes
>   -DarchetypeArtifactId=karaf-assembly-archetype -DarchetypeVersion=4.1.0

then I've added following features:

```
                <bootFeatures>
                    <feature>standard</feature>
                    <feature>jpa/2.5.0</feature>
                    <feature>transaction-api/1.2.0</feature>
                    <feature>transaction</feature>
                    <feature>eclipselink</feature>
                    <feature>pax-jdbc-config</feature>
                    <feature>pax-jdbc-postgresql</feature>
                </bootFeatures>
```

When I download karaf 4.1.0 distribution from Apache site, and install features using feature:install, everything works fine, however, in the distribution built by plugin I get the error:

> Unable to start blueprint container for bundle
>   org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/1.1.1 due to unresolved
>   dependencies [(objectClass=javax.transaction.TransactionManager)]
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:371)
>   [15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]    at
>   org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
>   [15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [?:?]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [?:?]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:?]
>
> 2017-03-22T11:03:51,401 | ERROR | Blueprint Extender: 1 |
>   BlueprintContainerImpl           | 15 -
>   org.apache.aries.blueprint.core - 1.7.1 | Unable to start blueprint
>   container for bundle org.apache.aries.transaction.blueprint/2.1.0 due
>   to unresolved dependencies
>   [(objectClass=javax.transaction.TransactionManager)]
>   java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException     at
>   org.apache.aries.blueprint.container.BlueprintContainerImpl$1.run(BlueprintContainerImpl.java:371)
>   [15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]    at
>   org.apache.aries.blueprint.utils.threading.impl.DiscardableRunnable.run(DiscardableRunnable.java:48)
>   [15:org.apache.aries.blueprint.core:1.7.1]    at
>   java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
>   [?:?]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>   [?:?]     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>   [?:?]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [?:?]

I've found the service in OSGi registry in web console:

```
Service 266 - [org.apache.aries.transaction.AriesTransactionManager, javax.transaction.TransactionManager, javax.transaction.TransactionSynchronizationRegistry, javax.transaction.UserTransaction, org.apache.geronimo.transaction.manager.RecoverableTransactionManager] (pid: n/a)
  from Bundle 143 - Apache Aries Transaction Manager (org.apache.aries.transaction.manager), version 1.3.2
    service.bundleid: 143
    service.scope: singleton
```

What is wrong here? Do maven plugin do something wrong, or the problem is, that plugin uses instable version of artifacts?

Answer (score 1):

Without looking at the wiring of your OSGi bundles it's not possible to be certain, but the most likely explanation is down to the toxic `javax.transaction` package. When specifying JTA it became clear that certain types in "core Java" needed to implement certain JTA interfaces, for example SQL `Connection` objects need a related `XAResource`. This forced some of the JTA API into core Java, but rather than putting the complete API into the base runtime only a few types were added. This leads to a split package between the Java Runtime and JTA, and causes big problems in modular systems (which don't normally allow you to see the same package from multiple sources simultaneously.

In this case the Transaction Manager service must be using the JTA API from a bundle deployed inside the OSGi framework (the base runtime doesn't include the `TransactionManager` interface). The consuming bundle, on the other hand, is probably importing `javax.transaction` from the system bundle (i.e. the Java runtime). As these two bundles don't share a view of the service API they then cannot share the OSGi service.

The only real way to fix this is by putting the JTA API on the Java classpath and exposing it through the system bundle at the correct version using a launch property such as:

```
org.osgi.framework.system.packages.extra=javax.transaction;version=1.2
```